# How to change values of bash array elements without loop

Tags: arrays, bash

```
array=(a b c d)
```

I would like to add a character before each element of the array in order to have this

```
array=(^a ^b ^c ^d)
```

An easy way to do that is to loop on array elements and change values one by one

```
for i in "${#array[@]}"
do
    array[i]="^"array[i]
done
```

But I would like to know if there is any way to do the same thing without looping on the array as I have to do the same instruction on all elements.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Use Parameter Expansion:

```
array=("${array[@]/#/^}")
```

From the documentation:

> ### ${parameter/pattern/string}
>
> Pattern  substitution.   The  pattern  is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname
>                 expansion.  Parameter is expanded and the longest match of pattern  against  its  value  is
>                 replaced  with  string.  If pattern begins with /, all matches of pattern are replaced with
>                 string.  Normally only the first match is replaced.  If pattern  begins  with  #,  it  must
>                 match  at  the  beginning of the expanded value of parameter.  If pattern begins with %, it
>                 must match at the end of the expanded value of parameter.  If string is  null,  matches  of
>                 pattern  are  deleted  and the / following pattern may be omitted.  If parameter is @ or *,
>                 the substitution operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the  expansion is the resultant list.  If parameter is an array variable subscripted with @ or *, the
>                 substitution operation is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is
>                 the resultant list.

Comment: I have just another question. I would like to know if I can use this to change just a subset of an array
because I obtain a syntax error when I run this
    array[@]:i:10=(${array[@]:i:10}/#/^})

Comment: @tuxworker  I think you need to assign your sub-range array to another array variable first, then add the prefixes.

Comment: NB: If you have IFS=$'\n' (to handle names with whitespace) then the command will not keep the original array structure. It will just make array contain only 1 item (a string list), with all the changed strings. As seen if you run: `declare -p array` afterwards.

Comment: `DIRS=("${DIRS[@]/%/\/module}")` use `%` instead of `#` to substitute at the end.  https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

Comment: what if we want to add a number to all elements in an array?

Comment: @beliz: Do you mean "add" in the arithmetic sense?

Comment: @choroba yes. is it possible?

Comment: @beliz: I don't think it's possible without a loop.

Answer (score 10):

This way also honor whitespaces in array values:

```
array=( "${array[@]/#/^}" )
```

Note, this will FAIL if array was empty and you set previously

```
set -u
```

I don't know how to eliminate this issue using short code...

Comment: Maybe `array=("${array[@]:+${array[@]/#/^}}")`, but I can't reproduce it (empty array + `set -u`) with neither `bash-4.4.0`, nor `bash-4.1.5`. In the latter you need this construct for iterating over an array with `for`, though.

Comment: How would you mark start and end of the string? From this: `declare -a arr=(12 123); echo "${arr[@]/12/00}"` I want `00 123` but I'm getting `00 003`.

Comment: `DIRS=("${DIRS[@]/%/\/module}")` use `%` instead of `#` to substitute at the end.  https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html