# Remove Beginning And End Of Each Element In Array In Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, unix

I have a bash array with 3 elements and I need to remove the first X number characters from all the elements and the last Y number of characters from all the elements.  How can this be achieved.  Example below:

```
echo ${array[@]}
random/path/file1.txt random/path/file2.txt random/path/file3.txt
```

I would like this array to become

```
echo ${array[@]}
file1 file2 file3
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change values of bash array elements without loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744031/how-to-change-values-of-bash-array-elements-without-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will go with one shot:

```
$ a=( "/path/to/file1.txt" "path/to/file2.txt" )
$ basename -a "${a[@]%.*}"
file1
file2
```

Offcourse, can be enclosed in $( ) in order to be assigned to a variable.

Comment: This does exactly what I wanted, than you!

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this in just one step; you can, however, remove the prefixes first, then the suffixes.

```
array=( "${array[@]##*/" )  # Remove the longest prefix matching */ from each element
array=( "${array[@]%.*}" )  # Remove the shortest suffix match .* from each element
```

Comment: It is important to double-quote `${NAME[@]}`, otherwise it joins array content.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use basic string manipulation there:

```
echo ${array[@]##*/}
```

Or, to assign it to the array:

```
array=(${array[@]##*/})
```

Comment: This only does half of what the question asks.

Comment: Ah check, well, I only added is as placeholder until we have enough duplicate votes anyway ;)